# Reduce all pairwise comparisons in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, inequalities

I have a list of 37 values, like $2d^2$ and $2d(1-d^2)$. I know I can use `Reduce[]` to solve an inequality of the values. For example,

```
Reduce[2 d^2 >= (2 d (1 + d^2)), d]
```

returns

```
d<=0
```

However, to retype this function for each pairwise comparison for all 37 elements in the list would be exhausting and redundant.

How can I use `Reduce[]` to solve inequalities of all pairwise comparisons of elemetns in a list?

I tried

```
For[j = 1, j = 37, j++,For[i = 1, i = 37, i++,Print[Reduce[{mylist[[i ;; i]] >= mylist[[j ;; j]]}, d]]]]
```

and

```
Do[Reduce[{mylist[[i ;; i]] >= mylist[[i + 1 ;; i + 1]]}, d], {i, 6}]
```

but there was no output.

I also tried

```
Do[Print[Reduce[mylist >= mylist, d]], {mylist}]
```

which returned a list of $d\in \mathbb{R}$, which is not at all what I'm expecting.

Comment: try `BlockMap[Reduce[#,d]&@@#&, mylist,2,1]`?

Comment: could you let us have the list of 37 inequalities? thanks

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G This should help with a reproducible example:

`mylist={0,2,4,2d,2d^2,2d(1+d),-(2(1+d)+((4d^3)/(1-d)))(d-1)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mylist = {0, 2, 4, 2d, 2d^2, 2d(1+d), -(2(1+d)+((4d^3)/(1-d)))(d-1)} ;
```

For pairs of consecutive elements you can use [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
BlockMap[Reduce[#[[1]] >= #[[2]], d] &, mylist, 2, 1]
```

> {False, False, d <= 2, 0 <= d <= 1, d <= 0, 
>    d <= -(1/Sqrt[2]) || 1/Sqrt[2] <= d <= 1}

Alternatively, you can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[Reduce[# >= #2, d] &, {Most@mylist, Rest@mylist}]
```

> same result

For all possible pairs, use [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
Reduce[#[[1]] >= #[[2]], d]& /@ Tuples[mylist, {2}]
```

> {True, False, False, d <= 0, d == 0, -1 <= d <= 0, 
>    d <= Root[1 - #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], True, True, False, 
>    d <= 1, -1 <= d <= 1, 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= d <= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 
>    d <= 1/2, True, True, True, 
>    d <= 2, -Sqrt[2] <= d <= Sqrt[2], -2 <= d <= 1, d <= 1, d >= 0, 
>    d >= 1, d >= 2, d ∈ Reals, 0 <= d <= 1, d == 0, 
>    d <= Root[1 - # - #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], d ∈ Reals, 
>    d <= -1 || d >= 1, d <= -Sqrt[2] || d >= Sqrt[2], d <= 0 || d >= 1, 
>    d ∈ Reals, d <= 0, d <= Root[1 - 2 #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], 
>    d <= -1 || d >= 0, 
>    d <= 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) || d >= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 
>    d <= -2 || d >= 1, d ∈ Reals, d >= 0, d ∈ Reals, 
>    d <= -(1/Sqrt[2]) || 1/Sqrt[2] <= d <= 1, 
>    d >= Root[1 - #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], d == 0 || d >= 1/2, d >= 1, 
>    d >= Root[1 - # - #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], 
>    d >= Root[
>     1 - 2 #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], -(1/Sqrt[2]) <= d <= 1/Sqrt[2] || 
>     d >= 1, d ∈ Reals}

**Update:** Form your example in the comments, it seems that you need [`Subsets`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html):

```
Reduce[#[[1]] >= #[[2]], d]& /@ Subsets[mylist, {2}]
```

> {False, False, d <= 0, d == 0, -1 <= d <= 0, 
>    d <= Root[1 - #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], False, d <= 1, -1 <= d <= 1, 
>    1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= d <= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), d <= 1/2, 
>    d <= 2, -Sqrt[2] <= d <= Sqrt[2], -2 <= d <= 1, d <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1, 
>    d == 0, d <= Root[1 - # - #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], d <= 0, 
>    d <= Root[1 - 2 #^2 + 2 #^3& , 1, 0], 
>    d <= -(1/Sqrt[2]) || 1/Sqrt[2] <= d <= 1}

If needed, use [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) to get transform `Root` expressions:

```
ToRadicals @ %
```

> {False, False, d <= 0, d == 0, -1 <= d <= 0, 
>    d <= 1/6 (1 - 1/(53 - 6 Sqrt[78])^(1/3) - (53 - 6 Sqrt[78])^(
>        1/3)), False, d <= 1, -1 <= d <= 1, 
>    1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= d <= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), d <= 1/2, 
>    d <= 2, -Sqrt[2] <= d <= Sqrt[2], -2 <= d <= 1, d <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1, 
>    d == 0, d <= 
>     1/6 (1 - 7/(44 - 3 Sqrt[177])^(1/3) - (44 - 3 Sqrt[177])^(1/3)), 
>    d <= 0, d <= 
>     1/3 (1 - 2^(2/3)/(23 - 3 Sqrt[57])^(1/3) - (23 - 3 Sqrt[57])^(1/3)/
>        2^(2/3)), d <= -(1/Sqrt[2]) || 1/Sqrt[2] <= d <= 1}

Comment: With `mylist={0,2,4,2d,2d^2,2d(1+d),-(2(1+d)+((4d^3)/(1-d)))(d-1)}`, `BlockMap[Reduce[#[[1]] > #[[2]], d] &, mylist, 2, 1]` returns a list of 6 elements, whereas I would expect a list of 21 elements, which is all unique pairwise comparisons.

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt, please see the update.

Comment: The `Reduce[#[[1]]<=#[[2]],d]&/@Subsets[ mylist,{2}]` is exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help. You've saved me a lot of labor and heartache.

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept and welcome to mma.se.

Comment: I think he wanted >=  but the method of @kglr is great:  Reduce[#[[1]]>=#[[2]],d]&/@Subsets[myList,{2}]

Comment: thank you @MarkR; updated with the correction.